# how to connect soap request to php request

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

below I have attached my soapui request. When I use this PHP code, getting response from the soapui is not working. Please help me find a solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-17855236" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>WSBENZTRAVELS</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">p@ss1234</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body xmlns:ns2="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">

    <ns2:OTA_AirAvailRQ EchoToken='11868765275150-1300257933' PrimaryLangID='en-us' SequenceNmbr='1' Target='LIVE' TimeStamp='2018-10-08T11:39:35' Version='20061.00'><ns2:POS><ns2:Source TerminalID='Farhath/Farhath'><ns2:RequestorID ID='WSBENZTRAVELS' Type='4' /><ns2:BookingChannel Type='12' /></ns2:Source></ns2:POS><ns2:OriginDestinationInformation><ns2:DepartureDateTime>2018-10-30T00:00:00</ns2:DepartureDateTime><ns2:OriginLocation LocationCode='CMB' /><ns2:DestinationLocation LocationCode='RUH' /></ns2:OriginDestinationInformation><ns2:OriginDestinationInformation><ns2:DepartureDateTime>2018-11-30T00:00:00</ns2:DepartureDateTime><ns2:OriginLocation LocationCode='RUH' /><ns2:DestinationLocation LocationCode='CMB' /></ns2:OriginDestinationInformation><ns2:TravelerInfoSummary><ns2:AirTravelerAvail><ns2:PassengerTypeQuantity Code='ADT' Quantity='1' /></ns2:AirTravelerAvail></ns2:TravelerInfoSummary></ns2:OTA_AirAvailRQ>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Use the PHP SOAP client  class https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question to fix formatting and grammar. You have only attached some xml (is this some request param?) but no PHP code, please add it, too. And if the credentials inside your XML are not public, please remove them from your post